# Как провести валидацию фомы не вызывая события submit?

Tags: jquery, form, валидация

Есть необходимость проверить корректность заполненния полей формы и в случае успеха показать пользователю доп.ссыллки URL которых состоит из ранее заполненных полей офрмы.

На форме работает jquery.validate но он проверяет когда пользователь пытается нажать на кнопку "Найти", т.е. вызывает submit. Скажите как можно проводить проверку фомы и получать например true или false в процессе заполнения формы, например по событию change()?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать плагин [валидации](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules) который позволяет задавать правила методом .rules()

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// initialize the plugin
$('#myform').validate({ 
    // other options,
    rules: {
        // other rules,
        weight: {
            required: true,
            max: 50 // initial value on load
        }
    }
});

// change the rule on checkbox and update displayed message dynamically
$('#check').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#weight').rules('add', {
            max: 100
        });
    } else {
        $('#weight').rules('add', {
            max: 50
        });
    };
    $('#weight.error').each(function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });
});});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hGxS/)